# visually plotting a value going to infinity in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to reproduce the Dirac Delta function:

[image: Dirac Delta Function]

my code:

```
x = -30:1:30;
y = zeros(1,numel(x)); %sets all values initially to zero
y(x==0)= inf; % the point corresponding to x=0 is set to inf
plot(x,y,'d')
axis([-40 40 0 inf])
```

My code produces:

[image: My figure]

Comment: `x=[-30,0,0,0,30]` `y=[0,0,80,0,0]` `plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with `stem`, specifying its `'Marker'` as an up arrow...

```
% Open figure
figure;
% Blue stem plot at x=0, to y=75. Marker style is up arrow
stem(0, 75,'color','b','linewidth',2,'marker','^')
% Add infinity label at x=0, y = 82 = 75 + fontsize/2, where we plotted up to 75
text(0,82,'∞','FontSize',14)
% Set axes limits
xlim([-40,40])
ylim([0,90])
```

You can see the [output plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEyDo.png), but see the edit below for an improved version.

Note, of course you should choose a y value which is large relative to any other data on the plot. In this example I chose 75 to roughly match your desired example plot. MATLAB can't plot a value at `inf` because, well, where does infinity sit on the y axis?

---

Edit: You can indicate the y-axis is broken with additional `'≈'` characters as suggested by Marco in the comments. Combining `xlim` and `ylim` into one `axis` call, and changing the y-axis ticks to help indicate the axis break, we get this result:

```
stem(0, 80,'color','b','linewidth',2,'marker','^')
text([-42,0,38], [80,87,80], {'≈','∞','≈'}, 'Fontsize', 14)
axis([-40, 40, 0, 100])
yticks(0:20:60)
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: In addition to show the `≈` on the y-axis you could add something like `text(-41.7, 75, '≈', 'Fontsize', 20)` and `text(41.7, 75, '≈', 'Fontsize', 20)` and not show yticks above 70.

Comment: @Marco you can do this with one call to `text` like so: `text([-42,38], [80,80], '≈', 'Fontsize', 20)` and then a call to `yticks` like so: `yticks(0:20:60)`

Comment: Heh. Nice. Dirac would be proud. +1.

Answer (score 3):

To show infinity, you should not set `y` to infinity. To do this, you can set `y` to a large value proportional to the axis values. For example if axis would be like `[min_x max_x min_y max_y]`, you can set `y(x==0) = max_y*10`.

In your case you will have:

```
x = -30:1:30; min_x = min(x) - 10; max_x = max(x) + 10;
y = zeros(1,numel(x)); 
% compute values of y here
% ...
min_y = min(y) - 10; max_y = max(y) + 10;
y(x==0)= 10 * max_y; 
plot(x,y,'d');
axis([min_x max_x min_y max_y]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the tick property in Matlab plot as described below

[image: screenshot]